# Bind the output of a method before using or call the method when you need its output?

Tags: python

In both examples, `class.method()` returns a list.

Example A:

```
if class.method():
    for i in class.method():
        # do stuff
```

Example B

```
list = class.method()
if list:
    for i in list:
        # do stuff
```

Which is better? It would seem to me that in some languages (but I don't know which), example A would result in `class.method()` being needlessly evaluated twice, and example B would be best practice. However, perhaps other languages (again not knowing which) might retain the output of a method in memory in case that method is called again, therefore avoiding having to do the same evaluation twice and resulting in little difference between examples A and B. Is this so? If so, can you give examples of a language for each case? And the real reason for the question: which is best practice in Python?

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time. Asking about Python and other languages are two different questions. As well, asking a broad question like "what languages do this?" is arguably off-topic. See [ask]. Please [edit] the question to narrow it down

Comment: Also, best practice is subjective, so it would help to add specific criteria or context to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your Python interpreter has JIT capabilities, the method will be evaluated every time you call it.

And even when the JIT compilation is possible, methods have to be proven by the compiler / interpreter that they do not have any side effects, that is they are deterministic.

For example, consider a method that pulls data from a database or a method that contains a call to a random number generator:

```py
import random

def method():
    return random.uniform(0.0, 1.0)
```

Output of such a method cannot be saved in memory because the second time you call it, it may change.

On the other hand, getter methods that accumulate data are a great example of a deterministic method, given that they do not call a non-deterministic method in their body.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Example:
    a : list
    b : list

    def method(self):
        return self.a + self.b
```

In practice, you are better of to not assume anything from the compiler / interpreter and do these small, easy to do optimizations yourself. You also have to consider that your code can be run on multiple platforms, which further complicates things.

So I would recommend you to call the `method` only once and save its output in a temporary variable:

```py
result = class.method()

if result :
    for i in result:
        # do stuff
```

And given that it's Python, I recommend to ask for forgiveness with the `try` keyword if most of the time you run the method, its output is not `None`:

```py
result = class.method()

try:
    for i in result:
        # do stuff

except TypeError:
    pass
```